# Does Perl's Net::Cassandra module support UTF-8?

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, nosql, cassandra

I've run into a really strange UTF-8 problem with `Net::Cassandra::Easy` (which is built upon `Net::Cassandra`): UTF-8 strings written to Cassandra are garbled upon retrieval.

The following code shows the problem:

```
use strict;
use utf8;
use warnings;
use Net::Cassandra::Easy;

binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

my $key = "some_key";
my $column = "some_column";
my $set_value = "\x{2603}"; # U+2603 is ☃ (SNOWMAN)
my $cassandra = Net::Cassandra::Easy->new(keyspace => "Keyspace1", server => "localhost");
$cassandra->connect();
$cassandra->mutate([$key], family => "Standard1", insertions => { $column => $set_value });
my $result = $cassandra->get([$key], family => "Standard1", standard => 1);
my $get_value = $result->{$key}->{"Standard1"}->{$column};
if ($set_value eq $get_value) {
    # this is the path I want.
    print "OK: $set_value == $get_value\n";
} else {
    # this is the path I get.
    print "ERR: $set_value != $get_value\n";
}
```

When running the code above `$set_value eq $get_value` evaluates to `false`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably needs an Encode::decode_utf8 after reading.  (And really, an Encode::encode_utf8 for writes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `use Encode;` to the beginning of your script, and pass variables through `Encode::decode_utf8`. For example:

```
my $get_value = $result->{$key}->{"Standard1"}->{$column};
$get_value = Encode::decode_utf8($get_value);
```

Outputs:

```
OK: ☃ == ☃
```

When you set `$set_value` to "\x{2603}", Perl detects the wide character and sets the string encoding to UTF-8 for you. To confirm this, print the return value of `Encode::is_utf8($set_value)`.

Unfortunately, once this string goes into Cassandra and back out again, the encoding information is lost. It appears that Cassandra is encoding-agnostic. Calling `Encode::decode_utf8` tells Perl that you have a string containing a UTF-8 byte sequence, and that it should be converted into Perl's internal representation for Unicode. As jrockway points out, you should also call `Encode::encode_utf8` on any strings before they are sent to Cassandra, although in most cases Perl already knows they are UTF-8, for example if you've opened a file with the `:utf8` encoding layer.

If you use UTF-8 often, you might want to write a wrapper over Net::Cassandra::Easy to do this automatically.

Finally, you don't need `use utf8;` unless your Perl *source code* (variable *names*, comments etc.) contains UTF-8 characters. Perl can handle UTF-8 *strings* whether you specify `use utf8;` or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm afraid that does not solve the problem since \u{2603} is "☃" and not "â". The output I'm expecting is hence "OK: ☃ == ☃" and not "OK: â == â".

Comment: Oops, using PuTTY and forgot to set UTF-8 character set. I'll get back to you.

Comment: With UTF-8 the code above shows "OK: ☃ == ☃". Answer updated.